# How to run skype.exe from bat file

Tags: batch-file

I want to run follwing (working) windows command in bat file

```
C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe /secondary
```

I have placed following instructions in a bat file but it is not running

```
start "My Skype Runner" "C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" "secondary"
```

Can some one guide me what Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried following and it worked :

```
start "My Skype Runner" "C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" "/secondary"
```

Answer (score 2):

Write the following command in batch file:

```
"C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this in note pad saved it as 3skypes.bat maybe not prettiest but works! Enter your own skype users and passwords, just saying...

```
start "Open3Skypes" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe" /username:XXX /password:YYY

ping -n 10 localhost 

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe" /secondary /username:AAA password:BBB

ping -n 10 localhost 

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\skype.exe" /secondary /username:CCC /password:DDD
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try simply:

```
"C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" /secondary
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, but the only working solution for windows 8.1 was:

> start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your computer, but on mine, Skype is located at:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe"
```

Comment: that you have `(x86)` in the path shows you are running a 64 bit Windows - it's just Program Files with a 32 bit version of Windows

Comment: I'm aware of that; the point is more the 'Phone\' rather than the '(x86)' part.

Answer (score 0):

Guys I have written a small c# console app for this over the weekend. The user needs to have skype desktop installed and not the UWP version of the latest skype 8+. I have generated 2 batch files on for *86 version and one for *64 version that are in the root of the project. Fmrom solution expolorer the options for the files are Build Action : Compile and Copy to Output Directory: Do not Copy.[VS Solution Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPs3a.png) Also Code can be downloaded from:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XmdnPr03WLkPbh9M2IHHPu05Mkmkzlc5

```
namespace MultipleSkype
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            int InstanceNumbers = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Instances of Skype to Open");
            InstanceNumbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            createInstances(InstanceNumbers);

        }

        private static void createInstances(int instanceNumbers)

        {

            string fileName="";
            string x86 = @"C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone\skype.exe";
            string x64 = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Skype for 
            Desktop\Skype.exe";

            Console.WriteLine("Checking Version of Skype...");
            if (checkIf86OR64(x86)) { fileName = "skype86.bat"; } else if 
            (checkIf86OR64(x64)) { fileName = "skype.bat"; }

            for (int i = 0; i < instanceNumbers; i++)
            {
                Process proc = null;
                try
                {

                    proc = new Process();

                    proc.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
                    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
                    proc.Start();
                    proc.WaitForExit();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());

                }
            }
        }
        //Check that dir exists
        private static bool checkIf86OR64(string dir)
        {
            if (File.Exists(dir))
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```